# What is the default virtual terminal font?

Tags: tty, fonts

From the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Console_fonts):

> By default, the [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) uses the kernel built-in font with a [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP437) character set, but this can be easily changed.

I actually prefer this font over the default 'Monospace' font. Where can I extract/obtain a copy of this font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading Thomas Dickey's answer, I researched what [Codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) actually is, and it turns out that it's the font that's heavily associated with the DOS era.

I came across a site called [The Ultimate Oldschool PC Font Pack](http://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/fontlist/), which has a collection of TTFs that are (near) perfect replications of the old fonts that everyone loves.

I made a package for it called [ttf-ibm-vga8](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-ibm-vga8/) in the Arch User Repository. You can install on other distributions by moving it to the fonts folder.

Answer (score 3):

The wiki goes on to say:

> The kbd package provides tools to change virtual console font and font mapping. Available fonts are saved in the /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/ directory, those ending with .psfu or .psfu.gz have a Unicode translation map built-in.

as well as linking to a [makefile in Git](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/vt/Makefile#n4), which cites `cp437.uni` as the file to look for.

Like Arch, Debian uses the `kbd` package, and likely the same fonts.  I do not see "cp437" in the corresponding `console-setup-linux`.  Likely, the default `cp437` font is compiled into the kernel and not actually a file that you can load.